# Cross platform C# apps with SQLITE/SQL COMPACT Databases

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, architecture, cross-platform

When architecting a cross platform C# application (IE: planning on creating a mono version) what is the best path to take regarding the database implementation when using only local databases? Assume that in each of these implementations a practical separation of concerns exists.

- A.   Develop against SQL Compact and
  when porting to mono create an SQLITE
  version of the application?
- B.  Develop against SQLITE from the
  start?
- C.   Some other option?????

PS: Is there some specific reason/feature that one might prefer in either database implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not develop for SQLite from the start? It's available for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X and you don't need to change anything from one platform to another this way. There's a [Mono.Data.SqliteClient](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite) assembly if you need it.

Comment: +1 I'd probably use SQLite over SQL CE anyway even without any portability / cross platform questions.

Comment: @Kragen: each with its own merits, although I'd probably do the same.

Comment: @alex - Sorry to bump this, but could you tell me if its possible for me to use the same implementation of SQLite for all platforms? i.e. Can I use Mono.Data.Sqlite in my .net program and have it be compatible with mono from the get-go? I have tried adding the reference and it builds, but I recieve a "Unable to load DLL Sqlite3"